# How to select sum -or- 0 if no records exist?

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to write a query that returns the sum of all values that meet a certain criteria, but the query needs to return 0 if no rows are found, rather than null.  For example:

```
tab    
+---------------+-----+
| descr         | num |
+---------------+-----+
| hello there   | 5   |
| hi there      | 10  |
| hello         | 10  |
| hi there!     | 15  |
+---------------+-----+
```

This query:

```
SELECT sum(num) AS val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%hello%";
```

should, and does, return `15`.  However:

```
SELECT sum(num) AS val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%greetings%";
```

should return `0`, but does return `null`.

Can someone explain if this is possible?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(num), 0) AS val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%greetings%";
```

The [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function basically says "return the first parameter, unless it's null in which case return the second parameter" - It's quite handy in these scenarios.

Comment: This doesn't actually have the desired effect - this will also mask a `NULL` that's part of the `num` values themselves.

Comment: This doesn't work. If there are no rows to aggregate `coalesce` won't even be called. I don't understand how this has 122 upvotes.

Comment: works for me in postgres at least

Answer (score 15):

Check the [MySQL documentation for IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(num, 0)) as val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%greetings%";
```

Of course, this assumes your `num` field is nullable and doesn't have a default value. Another possible solution would be to set a default of `0` for the num field which should solve the issue you're having.

Comment: IFNULL should be outside SUM, otherwise if no rows are found it will  return null.

Comment: SUM already ignores NULL values. In all cases SUM(IFNULL(abc, 0)) == SUM(abc)

Comment: @Eloims Your comment seems to be false. I also assumed that but it was wrong, which is why I am here looking for an answer.

Comment: @ChadBefus I was indeed wrong. SUM will ignore NULLs, but if the column contains ONLY nulls, or the table is empty it returns NULL. Here is a fiddle to test this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hvBkzyMWKYx7mT6hKqKFS/0

Comment: @sesser this is not working with postgres

Comment: @SagarDavara OP specifically asked about mysql. I haven't used postgres enough to provide a solution for you but I'm sure the manual could shed some light

Comment: @sesser even if in mysql, if the join table does not have any rows that satisfy the where condition, then this will not work

Comment: @SagarDavara now we’re talking about joins? Use inner join so you don’t get null values.

Answer (score 7):

The short way is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(num), 0) as val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%greetings%";
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this properly, you may want to distinguish between the case where there are actual `NULL` results in the data you're summing, and the case where there are no values at all to sum.

Suppose we have the following:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+----------+------+
| descr    | num  |
+----------+------+
| hiya     |    5 |
| hi there |   10 |
| yo       | NULL |
+----------+------+
```

We would like empty sums to be zero, but sums involving `NULL` to be `NULL`.  One (rather torturous) way to do that is:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(has_null, NULL, total) AS sum FROM (
    ->    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num IS NULL), 0) AS has_null, COALESCE(SUM(num), 0) AS total
    ->    FROM t WHERE num < 'ciao')
    -> AS u;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(has_null, NULL, total) AS sum FROM (
    ->    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num IS NULL), 0) AS has_null, COALESCE(SUM(num), 0) AS total
    ->    FROM t)
    -> AS u;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(has_null, NULL, total) AS sum FROM (
    ->    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num IS NULL), 0) AS has_null, COALESCE(SUM(num), 0) AS total
    ->    FROM t WHERE descr < 'namaste')
    -> AS u;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
|   15 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT IF(has_null, NULL, total) AS sum FROM (
    ->    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(num IS NULL), 0) AS has_null, COALESCE(SUM(num), 0) AS total
    ->    FROM t WHERE descr > 'namaste')
    -> AS u;
+------+
| sum  |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Perhaps there's a better way I haven't thought of.

Unfortunately, the SQL standard [defines `SUM` to be null when no elements are summed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25435/why-does-ansi-sql-define-sumno-rows-as-null), and MySQL has no choice but to follow that standard.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
SELECT IF(SUM(num) IS NULL, 0, SUM(num)) AS val FROM tab WHERE descr LIKE "%whatever%";
```

IF() takes three parameters: (1) A statement, (2) the value to apply if the statement is true, and (3) the value to apply if the statement is false.