# SQL: How to to SUM two values from different tables

Tags: sql, database

I have a number of tables with values I need to sum up. They are not linked either, but the order is the same across all the tables.

Basically, I would like to take this two tables:

```
CASH TABLE  
London  540
France  240
Belgium 340

CHEQUE TABLE
London  780
France  490
Belgium 230
```

To get an output like this to feed into a graphing application:

```
London  1320
France  730
Belgium 570
```

Comment: Hint `UNION`, `GROUP BY` and `SUM` will be useful.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
select region,sum(number) total
from
(
    select region,number
    from cash_table
    union all
    select region,number
    from cheque_table
) t
group by region
```

Comment: curious, why union all vs union?

Comment: @fungusanthrax `UNION` by itself will remove non-distinct (duplicate) rows. `UNION ALL` will keep all rows in the union so that the sum is accurate

Answer (score 31):

```
SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(London), 0) FROM CASH) + (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(London), 0) FROM CHEQUE) as result
```

'And so on and so forth.

"The COALESCE function basically says "return the first parameter, unless it's null in which case return the second parameter" - It's quite handy in these scenarios." [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888404/1081016)

Comment: 'London' is an entry in the table not a column

Comment: In this way, when even one of the SUMs is NULL, the entire "result" will be null, so that's the simplest way but the least trusted way, unfortunately...

Comment: @TheCuBeMan, true, but that van be avoided by using COALESCE function

Answer (score 3):

you can also try this in sql-server !!

```
select a.city,a.total + b.total as mytotal from [dbo].[cash] a join [dbo].[cheque] b on a.city=b.city
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ca58/2)

or try using sum,union

```
select sum(total)  as mytotal,city
from
(
    select * from cash union
    select * from cheque
) as vij
group by city
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current structure, you could also try the following:

```
select cash.Country, cash.Value, cheque.Value, cash.Value + cheque.Value as [Total]
from Cash
join Cheque
on cash.Country = cheque.Country
```

I think I prefer a union between the two tables, and a group by on the country name as mentioned above.

But I would also recommend normalising your tables. Ideally you'd have a country table, with Id and Name, and a payments table with:
CountryId (FK to countries), Total, Type (cash/cheque)