# How to Get Data Sum from Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Example

There are three tables:  `A_TBL`,`B_TBL`,`C_TBL`

```
CREATE TABLE A_tbl (    
    NUM int
)
insert into a_tbl values('1000');

CREATE TABLE B_tbl (    
    NUM int 
) 
insert into B_tbl values('2000')

CREATE TABLE C_tbl (    
    NUM int
)
```

A_TBL

```
NUM
1000
```

B_TBL

```
NUM
2000
```

I want to put the sum of Tables A and B in Table C.

### Desired Output

`C_TBL`

```
NUM
3000
```

Comment: What have you tried so, and why didn't it work? Have you considered using a (`CROSS`) `JOIN` and the `+` operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How to to SUM two values from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436895/sql-how-to-to-sum-two-values-from-different-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL` :

```
INSERT INTO c_tbl(num)
  SELECT SUM(num) 
  FROM (SELECT a.NUM FROM a_tbl a UNION ALL
        SELECT b.NUM FROM b_tbl b
       ) ab;
```

Comment: How do I subtract?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries in a `select`:

```
insert into c (num)
    select ( (select sum(num) from a) + select sum(num) from b) )
```