# Return 0 as SUM result if no records are found

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to summarize the calories of activities per day for a specific user for the last 7 days (actual day is 7th day). There are tables user and activities and the mapping table user_activities.

The following example is for the user with id=1;

> Sum up calories each day last 7 days (this day 7th day) */

```
SELECT  
    DATE(a.end_time), SUM(a.calories)
FROM
    activities a
JOIN
    user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
WHERE
    uc.user_id = 1
    AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY 
    DATE(a.end_time) DESC
```

That query returns this result set:

```
2018-12-28   9600
2018-12-27   1200
2018-12-26   1200
2018-12-25   1200
2018-12-24   4800
2018-12-22   1200
```

Which is correct but now my problem is, as you can see in the list the 12-23-2018 is not listed because there are no activities on this date. Now I want to display

```
2018-12-23   0
```

instead of nothing.

How can I get the desired result?

Thanks for your help

I also tried with IFNULL and COALESCE but no luck so far

> Sum up calories each day last 7 days (this day 7th day) */

```
SELECT  
    DATE(a.end_time), SUM(a.calories)
FROM
    activities a
JOIN 
    user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
WHERE 
    uc.user_id = 1
    AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY
    DATE(a.end_time) DESC
```

Result:

```
2018-12-28   9600
2018-12-27   1200
2018-12-26   1200
2018-12-25   1200
2018-12-24   4800
2018-12-22   1200
```

Expected result:

```
2018-12-28   9600
2018-12-27   1200
2018-12-26   1200
2018-12-25   1200
2018-12-24   4800
2018-12-23      0
2018-12-22   1200
```

`Activities` table:

[image]

Comment: Please show an example of the actual data in your database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select sum -or- 0 if no records exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888390/how-to-select-sum-or-0-if-no-records-exist)

Comment: @Martin I added the links to show the data

Comment: Future point of note for DB questions; pictures of data are really hard for us to go and type in to check queries. Please aim to provide a set of CREATE/INSERT statemetns or even better a fiddle, like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81383a/3 . Updated my answer, btw

Comment: @CaiusJard I will try to make you a sqlfiddle now.

Comment: @CaiusJard here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbc268

entries in activities are not 30 entries yet

Comment: Ps If you don't have 30 entries you could always use a cross join to increase the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a chance your activities table doesn't have an activity listed on a particular day, then fa06's trick won't work out. A simple way to cover that case is to add some zero records on before you do your sum:

```
SELECT DATE(d), SUM(c)
FROM (
  SELECT  a.end_time as d, a.calories as c
  FROM activities a
  JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
  WHERE uc.user_id = 1
  AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 DAY, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY, 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY, 0
) z
GROUP BY DATE(d)
```

fa06's method relies on there being one record every day in the activities table. It's a valid way to approach the problem, but you haven't been specific about what data these tables contain (hint: when posting a db question, do include sample data from each table)

With this method we do our lookup as normal, but we also generate 7 fake rows with dates from the last 7 days and a 0 calorie count. When added onto real calorie counts, these are fat free ;) and when there is no data for a particular day, these stand alone to provide the 0

If you want more days, consider moving to a row generating pattern. MySQL doesn't have row generators like other DBs, but the simplest trick is to create 
 variable, init it with 0 then increment and use it upon every row returned from a table with at least 30 rows:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) DAY as dt, 0 as cal
FROM activities t, (SELECT @row := -1) r
LIMIT 30
```

The theory behind this is: the table has at least 30 rows, @row variable is inited to -1, and exists session-wide for the query. As rows are pulled out and returned, @row is incremented and then returned (so it's 0, 1, 2.. ) and this increasing count is used to subtract 0, 1, 2 etc days off of the current data, giving us a sequence of dates for the past 30 days

```
SELECT DATE(d), SUM(c)
FROM (
  SELECT  a.end_time as d, a.calories as c
  FROM activities a
  JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
  WHERE uc.user_id = 1
  AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 29 DAY
  UNION ALL

  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) DAY as dt, 0 as cal
  FROM activities t, (SELECT @row := -1) r
  WHERE @row < 30
) z
GROUP BY DATE(d)
```

Note that I wasn't able to test either of these queries; the second might have some minor syntax error. If it turns out not to work, and the error is nontrivial/something you cant fix let me know.

Debugging:

Run each of these queries in isolation. I don't know how many rows this will produce:

```
  SELECT  a.end_time as d, a.calories as c
  FROM activities a
  JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
  WHERE uc.user_id = 1
  AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 29 DAY
```

And this one should produce 30 rows. If it doesn't it will be because you didn't use a table with at least 30 rows:

```
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) DAY as dt, 0 as cal
  FROM activities t, (SELECT @row := -1) r
  LIMIT 30
```

Edit:

Fixed the bug with this - LIMIT was being applied after the union; this was giving undesired results

Comment: This solution works as desired. One more question is there a way to loop through the intervals instead of listing all. Because I also want to do this query for 30 days.

Comment: @Ikaurs this is the wrong way round - you should not be putting temporary data into the database only to be extracted at the same execution (as infered by your question here). Your database interaction level (ex. PHP) should do that for you. `if(empty($var['row])){ $var['row'] = 0; }` etc.

Comment: It works as expected but only shows entries from 2018-12-28 till 2018-12-15 that are only 14 entries.
Also when I change the limit to 7 it only shows 3 entries.

Comment: Seems need to `GROUP BY` before the `LIMIT` (or vice versa)

Comment: I fixed a bug where the 30 days query still had `AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY` but these things are really hard to debug without sample data. To be clear,if you don't have at least 30 rows in activities, you'll need to use another table that does have at least 30 rows in place of `activities t` (not `activities a`), or you'll have to repeat tables in a cartesian join pattern: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/82445

Comment: @Martin I can't see why you want the inner query grouped? It isn't here, and the query runs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81383a/3

Comment: I tried your updated query. But I got still the same issue. Please see my activities table in the description.

When I run the query now, I only get 10 results:
2018-12-28 9600  
2018-12-27 1200  
2018-12-26 1200  
2018-12-25 1200  
2018-12-24 4800  
2018-12-23 0  
2018-12-22 1200  
2018-12-21 0  
2018-12-20 0  
2018-12-10 3600  

Also when i change interval to 6 and limit to 7 i Only receive 3 results:
2018-12-28 9600  
2018-12-27 600  
2018-12-24 3600

Comment: Run each query (either side of the UNION ALL) in isolation and tell me what you get (I updated the answer to be explicit about this)

Comment: so I ran:
SELECT DATE(d), SUM(c)
FROM (
  SELECT  a.end_time as d, a.calories as c
  FROM activities a
  JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
  WHERE uc.user_id = 1
  AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
) z
GROUP BY DATE(d) DESC

and received:
2018-12-28 9600
2018-12-27 1200
2018-12-26 1200
2018-12-25 1200
2018-12-24 4800
2018-12-22 1200

with interval 29 I receive:
2018-12-28 9600
2018-12-27 1200
2018-12-26 1200
2018-12-25 1200
2018-12-24 4800
2018-12-22 1200
2018-12-10 3600

How can i put in code in the comment? thx

Comment: It looks `like this`

Comment: OK, so that query is working OK with INTERVAL 29 - you only have the 10th Dec that is older than 7 days. Now run `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) DAY as dt, 0 as cal
  FROM activities t, (SELECT @row := -1) r
  LIMIT 30` - does it return 30 rows (the past 30 days dates, and a column of 0 cal)?

Comment: I updated the activities table so I have now 46 rows in it. An the query
`SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (@row := @row + 1) DAY as dt, 0 as cal FROM activities t, (SELECT @row := -1) r LIMIT 30`

gives me 30 rows back with value 0

Comment: Found the bug.. it seems that `SELECT x UNION SELECT y LIMIT 30` was being done as `(SELECT x UNION SELECT y) LIMIT 30` and not `(SELECT x) UNION (SELECT y LIMIT 30)` as I was expecting. Changed the LIMIT to be `WHERE @row < 30` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using left join

```
SELECT  DATE(a.end_time), SUM(a.calories)
FROM activities a
left JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
Where uc.user_id = 1 AND DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(a.end_time) order by DATE(a.end_time) DESC
```

Comment: This query doesn't work it don't shows 0 for 2018-12-23.
Also the 2018-12-10 is now listed so the Interval doesn't work correctly.

2018-12-28 9600
2018-12-27 1200
2018-12-26 1200
2018-12-25 1200
2018-12-24 4800
2018-12-22 1200
2018-12-10 3600

Comment: Still 23th is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying it on my end and just updated the `SUM(a.calories)` to `IF(SUM(a.calories) IS NULL, 0, SUM(a.calories))`

Here you may try...

```
SELECT  DATE(a.end_time), IF(SUM(a.calories) IS NULL, 0, SUM(a.calories))
  FROM activities a
    JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id
  WHERE uc.user_id = 1
    AND
     DATE(a.end_time) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY
  GROUP BY DATE(a.end_time) DESC
```

Comment: If there is no row, there is nothing to coalesce

Comment: @Caius Jard I'm not using coalesce, if the value is null, it will set to 0

Comment: @Ikaurs, you mean you have not achieved to display all dates?

Comment: No the result is still: 
2018-12-28 9600
2018-12-27 1200
2018-12-26 1200
2018-12-25 1200
2018-12-24 4800
2018-12-22 1200

No 2018-12-23 is listed

Comment: This is caused because if the `SUM` is zero then both the `DATE` and the `SUM` columns need to be generated on the database. Only the SUM is being generated at the moment.

Comment: If that so, then I think you should display first the date range that you want to display. It seemed that the date you want would not depends on your Join

Comment: By "coalesce" I meant this pattern you have here of "if null then 0 else value", not the SQL function COALESCE, though they're conceptually the same thing; coalescing in  an SQL sense is replacing null values with non null values. The base problem with your solution is that there is no row for the 23rd date, so there is nothing to be NULL for your IF to work out. This is not an answer to the question; fix it or delete it

Comment: These issues can be resolved and worked around ***IF the OP edits their question and shows us an example of the exact data in their database***

Comment: @Caius Jard, yup. I think it should

Comment: But still will not work if the date does not depends on join

Answer (score 0):

This query should to the trick :

- the CTE dynamically generates a date range (this will go up to about 300 years ahead)
- the result is `LEFT JOIN`ed with the `activities` and `user_activities` tables
- the `COALESCE` function turns empty `SUM`s into `0` values

Query :

```
WITH v AS (
    SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date FROM
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
        (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v
    WHERE selected_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT v.selected_date, COALESCE(SUM(a.calories), 0)
FROM 
    v
    LEFT JOIN activities a on DATE(a.end_time) = v.selected_date
    LEFT JOIN user_activities uc ON uc.activity_id = a.id AND uc.user_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(a.end_time) DESC
ORDER BY v.selected_date
```